# What does the command 'c ..' do?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

What does the Linux terminal command 'c ..' do? I have tried it and it looks like it has moved me to the home directory, however, I don't think this is true.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ file c
c: ERROR: cannot open `c' (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, nothing - unless you have an alias set for 'c' in your `~/.bashrc` file, it shouldn't execute anything at all, as that doesn't correlate to any command which one would expect in a default linux install.

I would recommend checking your `~/.bashrc` file to see if there is a matching alias which will tell you what it could be doing - and failing that, try `which c` - this would show you the path to the executable if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't do anything. `cd ..` will move you up one directory.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal for more information, or type `man COMMAND` to see the manual page for any COMMAND in the terminal.